# Copy paste a multiline command into command line

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, copy-paste

I'm writing a doc about installation of my soft and I have to write things like

> Please do the following:
>
> ```
>   sudo apt-get update
>   sudo apt-get install python-dev cython portaudio19-dev
> ```

The idea is: people are going to **copy/paste**  these two lines into their `bash` and then hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

What's a clean way to write multiline commands, such that it will be copy/pasted into bash?

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python-dev cython portaudio19-dev
```

or

```
sudo apt-get update ;
sudo apt-get install python-dev cython portaudio19-dev
```

or

```
sudo apt-get update &&
sudo apt-get install python-dev cython portaudio19-dev
```

or something else?

*Note: of course, I could provide a `.sh` script, but here the question is more about: what's a clean way to write a multiline command, such that it'll work when copy/pasting it.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one isn't going to work in general if at all.

Option two is `;` but recognise that it says run command one after the other **irrespective** of whether the first ran successfully. So if first command failed the second one would run anyway.

Option three is `&&` which means in your example, run second command **only** if first command was successful.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything special, the CLI sees the invisible carriage return and then goes to the next line.  Just highlight, copy, and paste!

Answer (score 1):

Best is 3rd I think. With the first and second, all but the last command will be executed. Then you'll have to hit enter again.

Answer (score 1):

I personally use the double-ampersand (`&&`) and keep everything on one single line if I'm typing. If I'm copying and pasting into a PuTTY window, then I can just copy and paste, and all the commands get executed, as if I typed them in and pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd> manually after each line.

The additional great thing about the `&&` is that the command will stop if there is an error, and won't continue. This lets me see what part was wrong, and correct it (typo? Wrong working directory? Not root [my company doesn't use `sudo` -.-]?).